# When will a correct SQL yield a wrong result

Tags: sql, oracle

Sometimes you struggle for hours with a seemingly unreasonable result from an SQL query you believe to be correct.

Now and then it turns out that it is in fact an Oracle bug and that your SQL is correct.

Are there any shortcuts to knowing if that is the case - saving you a lot of time and frustration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to apply the NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION hint introduced in Oracle 10g.

If this yields the desired result you know you are facing an Oracle bug, as no hint should change the actual outcome of a query.

At the same time you may have solved your issue except that maybe your execution plan will not be satisfactory.

The bug you are facing (I don't know if it is a known bug) is that the Oracle optimizer may not interpret the intent of the original query correctly when transforming the query for better execution plan (merge views etc.). By using the hint you instruct the optimizer to not do so.

The phenomenon is most often seen with complex queries involving inline performance views.

Currently I don't have any code samples to reproduce this problem but I am working on it.

UPDATE:
It seems that this in fact what the hint is meant for - I found this:

> Finally for query blocks, note that view merging or subquery unnesting might affect the results we see, whereby query blocks can "disappear" completely. This means that our named query block will be "transformed out" of the query and a system-generated query block name used in its place. We can see examples of system-generated query block and alias names in our first detailed explain plan above. The implication of this, of course, is that some hints against named query blocks might not work as we expect them to because the named block doesn't really exist.
>
> We do have a couple of options, however. First, we can identify the system-generated query block/alias names using a detailed explain plan and then use these identifiers in our hints. Jonathan Lewis has a good discussion of this technique here. Alternatively, Oracle provides a NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION hint to avoid the transformations that caused the named query blocks to "disappear". However, this is quite a drastic approach as it means that Oracle will optimise the query exactly how we write it. The cost of losing the transformation might far outweigh the benefit of the hints we needed to apply to the disappearing query block in the first place.

[doumentation](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=316).