# Oracle SQL - group by char cast

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

Using the a char-cast in a group-by clause results something unexpected:

```
select cast(col as char(2)) from (
  select 'Abc' as col from dual
  union all
  select 'Abc' as col from dual
) group by cast(col as char(10));
```

The result is `'Abc       '` (10 characters long).
Intuitively, I would have expected Oracle to return one of the following:

- An error: 'not a group-by expression', as the group-by clause is another than the selection clause
- A result of length 2 `'Ab'`.

Replacing `cast(col as char(2))` with `cast(col as char(3))`, Oracle returns an error 'not a group-by expression'. This, again is a very strange behavior.

How can this be explained? What's the reason behind it?

I'm using Oracle SQL 11g.

Comment: I just tested on 11g and it produces the same results for values 1-11, except for 3.  Very strange indeed.  To me, this seems like a bug.  The return should be `'Ab'`.  The expected value is returned, if you use an aggregation function.

Comment: Why you are using group by  in a query that don't use aggregation function?

Comment: It could be caused by oracle misunderstanding the intention of the query. Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25792979/2436051.

Comment: @JensKrogsboell I tried with the NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION hint, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned above, I think there is a misunderstanding going on. o.O

I can't explain why it's doing this, but here's the pattern for the type of query you have:

If you generalize it a bit like this, where [A] and [B] are integers, and [STRING] is whatever text you want:

```
select cast(col as char([A])) from (
  select '[STRING]' as col from dual
  union all
  select '[STRING]' as col from dual
) group by cast(col as char([B]));
```

it looks like this always fails if one of the two conditions below is true (there may be others):

1. ( LENGTH([STRING]) < [B] OR LENGTH([STRING] > [B]) and [A] = LENGTH([STRING])
2. ( LENGTH([STRING]) = [B] AND [A] <> LENGTH([STRING]) )

Otherwise, it'll return a row.

But if you take your example that runs and use it in a CREATE TABLE statement, it's going to fail as it sets up the column width to be the 2 and can't fit the 3 character string coming in.

To add to the oddity, if you append something at the start and the end of the string like this:

```
select '\*'||cast(col as char([A]))||'\*' from (
  select '[STRING]' as col from dual
  union all
  select '[STRING]' as col from dual
) group by cast(col as char([B]));
```

This will only work if [A] >= [B], otherwise it fails on ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.

Curious...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the abstraction of the issue. It's indeed still a very strange behavior. I don't mark the answer as correct, as it's more an addition to my question than an explanation.